# Selenium:select multiple values from a list for event handling

Tags: selenium

I want to select alternate values from the list below.my current code is as follows:

```
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty

("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\softwares\\gecko\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://demoqa.com/selectable/");
System.out.println("url opened");
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[contains(@class,'ui-selectable')]"));

Thread.sleep(3000);

Actions builder= new Actions(driver);

Action build= builder.click(list.get(0)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build();

build.perform();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get all the elements, then go to the alternative elements and click on it.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='selectable']/li"));
```

Use the above xpath to get all the elements, once you got all the elements traverse to alternative elements.

```
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {     
builder.click(list.get(i)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
        System.out.println("item clicked" + list.get(i).getText());
    }
```